# What practical use is express.static when response.sendfile gives me more control?

Tags: node.js, express

The following line of code tells `node.js` where to find static files such as .htm, .css, .jpg etc. etc.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

However if I need to serve static files I can simply create routes to the exact files I need to serve.

```
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    response.sendfile('public/index.htm');
});
```

Except for edge cases why would anyone want to serve the static files of their website without routes?  Can I safely not include that line in my server app?  Maybe it has a practical use but as a noob I can't see it.  Thanks so much for any advice!

Comment: if you dont need it, you can just comment it out

Comment: It's 1) marginally simpler 2) shows a much more clear intent 3) potentially handled differently/smarter internally (as it's "abstracted away").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because if you have dozens of images, image sprites, JS and CSS files, fonts, audio, video, et cetera, to make more than an SPA (not saying there's anything wrong with that, but Express was definitely around prior to the popularity of SPAs and PWAs), you don't want to have to write an individual express route for *everything*. Your router files would be huge, and very, very few of those entries would have little to do with APIs (which is what Express and apps ought to be about).